# Custom approval workflow: task isn't obvious

Tags: 2010, workflow, approval-process

I have a custom workflow that uses the "Start Approval process" action in SP 2010. It fires off whenever a user creates or modifies an event on a specific calendar. The problem is that the approval process's email to the approver only contains a link directly to the calendar event, not to approve or reject the event. Using the built-in Approval workflow sends a link directly to approve/reject, but the "Start Approval process" email does not have that link.

My approvers cannot approve/reject without going into the workflow settings and manually finding the task associated with the given calendar event. How can I correct this behavior or rewrite the workflow so that the approval process is simpler?

For the record, the workflow is set up as in the below image, and no custom settings were set on the username other than the username itself (see the second image).

[image: workflow]

[image: blank "task process participants" window]

Comment: May I know customize the OOB workflow will only impact the site collection you are editing? Will it affect other site collection using the OOB workflow?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to provide the link yourself in the instructions section of the Select Participants window. If you use the add or change look-up you can put in the "Encoded Absolute URL" to lead people to the task.

Alternatively it may be simpler to just write the workflow yourself. I have one that uses the Send an Email action and then asks people to note their approval by putting the date in a column on my task list. I include the URL for the task and for the event in the email.